# Hechacham Yihyeh o Sachal - mi yodeya?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

### Who knows whether he will be a wise man or a fool?

### החכם יהיה או סכל - מי יודע?‏

The [controversial](http://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.30b.15) royal rumination [*Kohelet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecclesiastes) implies (in [2:19](http://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.2.19/he/Tanach_with_Nikkud?qh=&lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)) a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found in the fate of your ultimate intellectual status. Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about this and related topics.

What significant Judaism facts are there about whether you will end up smart or silly? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value of your personal store of brains, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Lazy gematria? You want to post answers based on lazy gematria? Here. I'll give you a head start. החכם יהיה או = סכל. You're welcome. Go to town.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Yeah, that gematria and the opening alliterations...

Comment: I have no idea what this is asking

Comment: @wfb That probably puts you on the *chacham* side of the ledger.

Comment: Does this fit the PTIJ policy?

Comment: @Yez Misinterpretation of a verse in Tanakh?

Comment: This is an important question, since, as _Koheles_ says, the one who knows the significance of whether he'll be wise or foolish will rule over all I've amassed through my labors and smarts.

Answer (score 0):

A smart person is not allowed to let it get too caught up in his wisdom:

> כה אמר יהוה, אל-יתהלל חכם בחכמתו
>
> Thus has Hashem said: Let not the wise praise himself over his wisdom.

Whereas, about the fool it says (Mishlei 26:3):

> ושבט לגו כסילים
>
> And a Lego stick is for the fool.

Clearly, only a fool would use a 'lego stick'-- the rest of us use lego **blocks**. Thus, only fool is allowed to get caught up in his mental state.